# Swift Button.setText doesn't work with gradient

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm new in Swift and I have a problem. my button do not set the text if I try to use the gradient. here is my code:

```
let gradient:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 9/255.0, green: 137/255.0, blue: 133/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    let colorTop = UIColor(red: 222.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 201.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor

    gradient.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    gradient.frame = LoginButton.bounds
    gradient.cornerRadius = 25.0


    LoginButton.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    LoginButton.setTitle("Login", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    LoginButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)


    self.view.addSubview(LoginButton)
```

Comment: Are you trying to set it for background of button or text

Comment: Try changing UIColor.blackColor to gradient

Comment: Have you tried `LoginButton.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, belowSublayer LoginButton.titleLabel.layer)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a sublayer works the same as adding a subview so adding the gradient layer may be covering the other layers where the text is drawn.

If you remove this line does it work?

```
LoginButton.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

If it does, try seeing how many layers are in `LoginButton.layer.sublayers` and try inserting the gradient layer behind one of those sublayers (wherever it looks the best) using one of the following methods:

```
-insertSublayer:above:
-insertSublayer:below:
-insertSublayer:atIndex:
```

Comment: it's right. I entered the sublayer as well and works:         LoginButton.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem:

```
LoginButton.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

Do not add any extra layers to a UIButton. It already knows how to draw itself. If you want it to have a gradient background, draw the gradient into an image and set that as the button's background image in the normal way.

Or make the button clear and put the gradient layer *behind* the button (though this is not as good).